# Hover over one div make another disapear

Tags: html, css

What is the best method to make one div disappear by hovering over another.

with the code provided below, when I used `.icon:hover + .info { display:none)` It just displays that div underneath rather than making it disappear. I'm unsure whether the placements of the divs in the html are affecting this or a mistake I could of made in the css

```css
.profile-container {
  background: #000;
  height: 400px;
}

.profile-info-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 1.6% 6%;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.twitter {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.google {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.linkedin {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.facebook {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  background: #d00009;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon:hover+.info {
  display: none;
}

.social i {
  padding: 15px;
}

fa fa-share-alt {
  color: #333!important;
}

.icon:hover+.social {
  display: block;
}

.icon:hover+.social {
  display: block!important;
}

.icon:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #d00009;
}

.social {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 3% 6%;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background: #d00009;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container_fluid section-3-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 profile-container">
          <div class="profile-info-box">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="social">
              <div class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
              <div class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div>
              <div class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></div>
              <div class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div id="hide" class="info">
              <p>Staff name<br>Job role</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using adjacent sibling combinator (+) to target`.icon:hover + .info`; however, `.info` does not immediately follow the `.icon` element. 

The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're on the right track in terms of html and css selectors. What you're missing is the correct selector.

`+` is used to select the immediate sibling of the element. What you are after is `~` which will select any matching sibling.

For example `.a + .b` will ONLY match the next element in the dom IF it has the class "b", whereas `.a ~ .b` will match ANY sibling element in the dom if it has the class "b".

As such, I've changed your selector to:

```
.icon:hover~.info {
  display: none;
}
```

### Edit

It is possible to specify multiple selectors to apply a rule to. To do this, you separate the selectors with a comma. I have tweaked the following selectors:

```
.icon:hover~.info
```

and

```
.icon:hover+.social
```

to

```
.icon:hover~.info, .social:hover~.info
```

and

```
.icon:hover+.social, .social:hover
```

As you are no longer hovering over `.icon` it turns back to red. Without altering the html (or adding javascript) there is nothing you can do to fix that.

```css
.profile-container {
  background: #000;
  height: 400px;
}

.profile-info-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 1.6% 6%;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.twitter {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.google {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.linkedin {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.facebook {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  background: #d00009;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
}

.social:hover+.info,
.icon:hover~.info {
  display: none;
}

.social i {
  padding: 15px;
}

fa fa-share-alt {
  color: #333!important;
}

.icon:hover+.social {
  display: block;
}
.social:hover,
.icon:hover+.social {
  display: block!important;
}

.icon:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #d00009;
}

.social {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 3% 6%;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background: #d00009;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container_fluid section-3-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 profile-container">
          <div class="profile-info-box">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="social">
              <div class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
              <div class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div>
              <div class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></div>
              <div class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div id="hide" class="info">
              <p>Staff name<br>Job role</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe it was that simple, I spent hours trying to fix this. When I hover over the social icons then it disappears back to the .info div. How can I make it stay active and go over to one of the social icons?

Answer (score 1):

Since `.info` is not a direct sibling of `.icon`, the selector `.icon:hover + .info` will return an empty set. What you want is a general sibling selector, i.e. `~`:

```
.icon:hover ~ .info {
  display: none;
}
```

Note that since CSS is cascading in nature, the sibling selectors `+` and `~` will only work when the sibling comes *after* the element. In your case it will work, but if you want to select a previous sibling, that is not possible using CSS.

```css
.profile-container {
  background: #000;
  height: 400px;
}

.profile-info-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 1.6% 6%;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.twitter {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.google {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.linkedin {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.facebook {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  background: #d00009;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon:hover ~ .info {
  display: none;
}

.social i {
  padding: 15px;
}

fa fa-share-alt {
  color: #333!important;
}

.icon:hover+.social {
  display: block;
}

.icon:hover+.social {
  display: block!important;
}

.icon:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #d00009;
}

.social {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 3% 6%;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background: #d00009;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container_fluid section-3-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 profile-container">
          <div class="profile-info-box">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="social">
              <div class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
              <div class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div>
              <div class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></div>
              <div class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div id="hide" class="info">
              <p>Staff name<br>Job role</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe it was that simple, I spent hours trying to fix this. When I hover over the social icons then it disappears back to the .info div. How can I make it stay active and go over to one of the social icons?

Comment: @jordan Think of it as a horizontal dropdown menu: your second request will need some refactoring of the DOM, and it's kind of out of the scope of your original question. Search around SO and you will find examples on implementing CSS-only dropdown menus.